# How to track multiple collisions between 2 sprites?

Tags: sprite-kit, sprite, collision-detection, collision, bit-masks

Here's an example, just for ease of understanding:

Sprite A is a ball.  Sprite B is a cube.  When the ball touches the cube once, I want the label to say first contact.  When the same ball touches the same cube again, I want the label to say second contact.  When the same ball , touches the same cube again, I want the label to say third contact.

How do I accomplish this?

It seems Sprite kit only allows 1 hit collisions between sprites to be programmed, which is enormously limited, in my opinion.  Especially, since I want to create an enemy that actually changes behaviour dependant on the amount of hits it receives from the player, not just the same action for every collision.

Comment: Your question doesn’t even make sense, you want the number of times two sprites touch each other over the course of your game, not multiple contacts.  You are asking for record keeping, which should not be expected from an API.

Comment: Well, Knight, don't mind if I call you Knight do you :).  Is does make sense, because I want to differentiate enemy behaviour based on contact number.  I've already worked it out using the point counter thing (see my answer below), and I used it for player health and enemy health.  So once I made contact with the enemy 10 times with my weapon, his health depleted and was removed from the scene.  Once the enemy made contact with his weapon on my ship (player) 3 times, my ship died and was removed and game over.  So it's not a tracking mechanism at all, its a practical way of conditional code.

Comment: No, you are asking a graphics API to do record keeping, that is the part that doesn’t make sense.  That is like asking an artist to count the number of people entering his studio.  Can he do it? Maybe. Is it his job? No. Is he going to give you a confused look and not understand if you are really asking him to do that?  Absolutely.

Comment: Well, Knight, the API must be very limited if it can't compute the number of times 2 sprites make contact.  It's like when 2 people meet, and then you say to your friend, "oh yeah I met Mike a few times, about 3."  That's really not hard for a human to do so it must be super easy for an API.  Furthermore, its useful for a programmer to know this so they can write conditional code depending on contacts or collisions made between 2 sprites.  It can be applied in many creative ways, such as player and enemy health and other variables such as speed, just think about it, Knight, will you.

Comment: no, your analogy is all wrong.  The tools can do record keeping quite easily, YOU just don’t know how to use them, and thus grabbing the wrong one.  You are using a wrench when you really needed a hammer.  Sure you can pound on that nail with the wrench, but you are going to work harder, and possibly break the wrench, board, of hurt yourself.

Comment: Noble Knight, what method can you thus use to return the a track of the number of times 2 sprites make contact, then?  Or how would you code/resolve the problem?  Sometimes when you're not an absolute pro at Swift and Spritekit you get creative lol

Comment: for something small you can use the `userData` of `SKNode` as a means of storing your data

Comment: cool, thanks Enchanted Knight :).  Also would like to add, that when 2 sprites collide and you have them set up with points using userData, you should make their bodies as bonded rectangles and not alpha masks, to ensure accurate tracking.  With alpha mask you get somewhat erratic numbers each time a collision is made, which what you don't need and very unusual to program that way, not to mention unpredictable.  With a 10 point system (UserData) each collision thus amounts to 10 points, when both sprites are bounded rectangles.

Comment: You don’t need rectangles, alpha mask works fine.  You just need to track every line, or ignore after the first, whichever info you need.  Alpha masks are more accurate collisions, it just requires a lot more processing.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way.  If you assign sprite A with points and use a cumulative score to keep track of the points you can then then use "score" as a collision counter.  So each time sprite A touched Sprite B the score would increment by 10 points, simply then saying if score == 100 for example ... program something or if score == 150 ... program something (did begin method) and it worked, allowing you to program different actions or whatever at each point of collision with the same sprites! Awesome.  Didn't think it would work but it did :)

Comment: That's interesting.  How would you then get accurate tracking with alpha masks using userData?